# Chrome / Opera extension clarification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera, opera-extension

Is it possible to create a big application (like 10 pages) as an extension? If I understand well, one can only have 1 background process and 1 page per extension, but I wanted the opinion of more experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Opera, but in Chrome you can have as many pages as you like (but single background page, which shouldn't limit anything).